# How To Discover Existing Terraform Version

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

Is there a way to figure out what version of Terraform might have been used to write a number of terraform config files?

My version of terraform is `v1.0.11`. I've just cloned a repo to work with and the terraform config syntax looks well old.

I've tried searching to see if `required_version` is set anywhere but nothing comes up.

Is there some kind of way to figure this out?

Comment: [Emidio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16993728/emidio-neto) is correct. Just to provide more context - quite often the same `.tf` files can works towards multiple Terraform versions. So in general there's no way to tell. Obviously, the `.tf` files might be using some fairly new features of Terraform language and thus the spectrum of versions could be limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to the `terraform.tfstate` you can find the version by searching for `terraform_version`on the tfstate json file.

Comment: `terraform state pull | jq .terraform_version` should help

Comment: @singh that will not help. `terraform state pull` will convert the state file to the match the version of terraform.exe being used locally, before displaying output. `jq .terraform_version` would always displays that converted version, not the version in the remote file.